# The color parameter for matplotlib's scatter is `c`, but `color` works too; prod. diff. results

Tags: python, matplotlib

I accidentally used `color` instead of `c` as color parameter in matplotlib's scatter plot (`c` is listed in the documentation`) It worked, but the result is a different one: Edge colors are gone by default. Now, I am wondering if this is desired behavior and about how and why this works...

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))

samples = np.random.randn(30,2)

ax[0][0].scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], 
            color='red',
            label='color="red"')

ax[1][0].scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1],
            c='red',
            label='c="red"')

ax[0][1].scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], 
            edgecolor='white', 
            c='red',
            label='c="red", edgecolor="white"')

ax[1][1].scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], 
            edgecolor='0', 
            c='1',
            label='color="1.0", edgecolor="0"')

for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        col.legend(loc='upper left') 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, but IMO, a little ambiguity of `matplotlib`'s documents.

The color of markers, can be defined by either `c`, `color`, `edgecolor` and `facecolor`.

`c` is in the source code of `scatter()` in `axes.py`. That is equivalent to `facecolor`. When you use `c='r'`, `edgecolor` is left undefined and the default in `matplotlib.rcParams` come in to effect, which has a default value of `k` (black).

`color`, `edgecolor` and `facecolor` are passed to the `collection.Collection` object `scatter()` returns. As you will see in the source code `collections.py` (`set_color()`, `set_edgecolor()` and `set_facecolor()` methods), `set_color()` basically calls `set_edgecolor` and `set_facecolor`, therefore set the two properties the same values.

These I hope should explain the behavior that your described in the OP. In the case of `c='red'` the edge is black and the face color is red. In the case of `color=red`, both the face color and the edge color are red.

Comment: +1 Might also be worth mentioning that `c` isn't quite equivalent to `facecolor`.  The `c` parameter is meant to (among other things) allow mapping the color of the markers to an array of values, while `facecolor`, `color`, etc, don't allow it.

Comment: Hi, @JoeKington, actually it is no longer the case in the new versions (>1.3.1), in the examples in OP, you can now pass, for example, `facecolor=matplotlib.cm.jet(samples)[:,1,:]` or `c=matplotlib.cm.jet(samples)[:,1,:]` to get a bag of colorful dots. Cheers!